# displaying interstitial admob ad every time a button is clicked

Tags: android, admob

I am working on an android app and I want to display interstitial ad every time a button in clicked. I have searched for it on stackoverflow and used the given suggestion but still I am not able to do it.
First I have declared interstitial ad as

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private AdRequest adRequest;
```

I have used this:

```
   mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

  btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Chm);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                         if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                                             mInterstitialAd.show();
                                         }
                                         mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


                                         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Btn.class);
                                         startActivity(i);
                                     }
                                 }
    );
```

But when I run the app, I click the above button I do not get any ad but when I click the back button after clicking the above button, I get the ad but that too only first time, not always. Please tell me my mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes Admob just can't find ad for you at the moment.

Comment: No, it is working always the same way. I am using test ads.

Comment: If you are using test ads then try to register your device as test device by adding `.addTestDevice();`  to your addRequest object providing test number from logcat as a parametar.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can fix it by including setAdListner

```
mInterstital.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            mInterstital.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    });
```